# Blazor Virtualize Adds empty space in list before cards

Tags: c#, blazor

If I use this code:

```
<div class="grid">   
        @foreach (var ski in skis)
        {
            <button class="skiCard" @onclick="(() => DetailSki(ski.Id))">
                @if (ski.Brand.Equals("Volkl"))
                {
                    <img src="images/volklmantra300.png" alt="Volkl Skis" style="width:100%" />
                }
                @if (ski.Brand.Equals("Head"))
                {
                    <img src="images/ski_image.png" alt="Head Skis" style="width:100%">
                }
                @if (ski.Brand.Equals("K2"))
                {
                    <img src="images/k2poacher300.png" alt="K2 Skis" style="width:100%" />
                }
                <div class="skiContainer">
                    <h4>@ski.Prefix-@ski.ShopCode</h4>
                </div>
            </button>
        }
    </div>
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GcvV.png)

If I change the foreach loop to a Virtualize component...

```
<div class="grid">   
       <Virtualize Items="skis" Context="ski">
            <button class="skiCard" @onclick="(() => DetailSki(ski.Id))">
                @if (ski.Brand.Equals("Volkl"))
                {
                    <img src="images/volklmantra300.png" alt="Volkl Skis" style="width:100%" />
                }
                @if (ski.Brand.Equals("Head"))
                {
                    <img src="images/ski_image.png" alt="Head Skis" style="width:100%">
                }
                @if (ski.Brand.Equals("K2"))
                {
                    <img src="images/k2poacher300.png" alt="K2 Skis" style="width:100%" />
                }
                <div class="skiContainer">
                    <h4>@ski.Prefix-@ski.ShopCode</h4>
                </div>
            </button>
        </Virtualize>
</div>
```

[This is now the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgW2K.png)

```
 .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(10rem, 100%), 1fr));
        gap: 1rem;
    }
    .skiCard {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .skiCard:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .skiContainer {
        padding: 2px 16px;
    }
```

My question: Why is that blank space there? I need to use the virtualize component because eventually the list will have a thousand entries in it, but that's kinda unsightly and I'd like to understand why its happening.

Comment: hard to say but I wonder why u have that class="grid" - can u try to remove it see if it helps? if not, look at the html that code is generating and try to see what element causes that space

Comment: I did play around with the css a little, it doesn't seem to be the issue. I'll put it in, in case there's something there

Comment: changing display to block did fix it, but now it doesn't really look the way I was wanting. Oh well, progress! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Virtualize` component generates two `divs` one before and one after the items. Those divs are necessary for the component to work.

[image]

Your `grid` has `gap: 1rem;` so it generates one extra gap between first div and first item and between last item and second div.

Also check this github [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28056#issuecomment-767674763) where it is stated that `Virtualize` component does not work with display `grid`. Steve Sanderson suggests to use `flex`.